# How to pass database name explicitly in application.properties file not through the datasource.URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

How to pass database name explicitly in
`application.properties`
file not through the datasource.URL

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an extra property and use it in the datasource-url like `${your-propname}`

result:

```
database-name=mydatabase

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/${database-name}
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
```

If you want to pass the database-name via a system-property you could use

```
database-name=${database:mydatabase}
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/${database-name}
```

Here you can pass the property via `java -Ddatabase=xxx`...
if this property is missing on startup then the default is used after the `:` (in example => mydatabase)

note: you should have a look at [config-files-profile-specific](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-files-profile-specific)

Comment: can we use the database same way ```${your-propname}```  in migration scripts too?

Comment: improved my answer, hope it helps

Comment: not sure what you mean with: usage in migration-scripts